# Ineffective subquery SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, the first is a table with information about customers, and the second contains the solds from customers (clientes, albarán_cliente) you can see the structure [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7fcdd), and what I need is to obtain a list of customers, another column whith sales for 2 years up to 1 year ago, and another column sales since 1 year ago until today.

Something like this:

```
Customers    Sales_from_2_years_ago_to_1_year_ago      sales_from_1_year_ago_to now
----------  ---------------------------------------     ---------------------------
aaa                     1000                                    2000
bbb                     850                                     900
ccc                     20000                                   15000
```

I can obtain this with subqueries:

```
select 
    c.nombre, (select sum(acc.importe) 
               from CLIENTES cc 
               join ALBARAN_CLIENTE acc on acc.codcli = cc.codcli 
               where fecalb > DATEADD(MONTH, -24, cast(getdate() as date))  
                 and fecalb < DATEADD(MONTH, -12, cast(getdate() as date)) 
                 and cc.NOMBRE = c.NOMBRE 
               group by cc.NOMBRE )[de -24 a -12 meses],

(select sum(acc.importe) from CLIENTES cc join ALBARAN_CLIENTE acc on acc.codcli=cc.codcli 
where fecalb>DATEADD(MONTH,-12,cast(getdate() as date)) and 
fecalb<cast(getdate() as date) and cc.NOMBRE=c.NOMBRE group by cc.NOMBRE)[de -12 a 0 meses]

from CLIENTES c join ALBARAN_CLIENTE ac on ac.codcli=c.codcli 
where fecalb>DATEADD(MONTH,-24,cast(getdate() as date)) 
group by c.NOMBRE
```

but the performance sucks,so i tried another options,
I read and tried using over(partition), But it does not seem to work for me, then i tried to use `WITH` :

```
WITH EQ AS


( select cc.nombre,sum(acc.importe)[suma1] 
from CLIENTES cc join ALBARAN_CLIENTE acc on acc.codcli=cc.codcli
where fecalb>DATEADD(MONTH,-24,cast(getdate() as date)) 
and fecalb<DATEADD(MONTH,-12,cast(getdate() as date))  
group by cc.NOMBRE
  )

, EQ2 AS    
(select cc.nombre,sum(acc.importe)[suma2] 
from CLIENTES cc join ALBARAN_CLIENTE acc on acc.codcli=cc.codcli
where fecalb>DATEADD(MONTH,-12,cast(getdate() as date)) 
and fecalb<cast(getdate() as date)  group by cc.NOMBRE
)

SELECT c.nombre, suma1,suma2
from CLIENTES c join ALBARAN_CLIENTE ac on ac.codcli=c.codcli 
left join EQ on EQ.NOMBRE=c.NOMBRE left join EQ2 on EQ2.NOMBRE=c.NOMBRE 
where fecalb>DATEADD(MONTH,-24,cast(getdate() as date)) 
group by c.NOMBRE,suma1,suma2
```

but  it takes many many more time(I've stopped him after a long time)

so my question is: **is ther a better way to obtain that result?**

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use conditional aggregation:

```
select cc.nombre,
       sum(case when fecalb > DATEADD(MONTH, -24, cast(getdate() as date)) and

                     fecalb < DATEADD(MONTH, -12, cast(getdate() as date))
                then acc.importe else 0
           end) as suma1,
       sum(case when fecalb > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, cast(getdate() as date)) and
                     fecalb < cast(getdate() as date)
                then acc.importe else 0
           end) as suma2
from CLIENTES cc join
     ALBARAN_CLIENTE acc
     on acc.codcli = cc.codcli  
group by cc.NOMBRE;
```

Comment: @Ion . . . This query should not generate that error.  The only column defining a group is `nombre` and the other expressions are all arguments to `SUM()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i dont know why when i tried something simillar give me an error because fecalb is not an Aggregate function. Your answer is perfect. Thanks alot for your help